# Enter/Return Key Triggers RegularExpressionValidator

Tags: asp.net, regex

I have a asp:Textbox that I am trying to make sure the user does not copy and paste in Tags. The below code works at checking for < and > but it also will throw the error message if a user hits the Enter or Return key to create a new line in the text box. What changes do I need to make to the ValidationExpression to allow the user to be able to use the Enter/Return keys, but not allow the < or > keys?

```
 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionVal3" runat="server"
                                    ErrorMessage="You cannot put tags into the text box (e.g. &lthtml&gt)"
                                    ControlToValidate="txtMSPC"
                                    ValidationExpression="^(?!<.*?>).*" ForeColor="Red" />
```

Comment: Do you mean no tags at the start or anywhere inside the string? Try `ValidationExpression="^(?![\\s\\S]*<[^>]*>)[\\s\\S]*"`. If you only run the validation on the server side, try `ValidationExpression="(?s)^(?!.*<[^>]*>).*"`

Comment: I am looking for client side and looking for tags anywhere in the string. For example: "This text is <b>Bold</b>"  should throw the error message. With your client side expression above, it allows the return, but it does not allow any characters or numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the client-side validation only, you may use

```
ValidationExpression="^(?![\\s\\S]*<[^>]*>)[\\s\\S]*"
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?![\\s\\S]*<[^>]*>)` - no `<` followed with 0+ chars other than `>` and then `>` in the string
- `[\\s\\S]**` - any 0+ chars

Comment: I am looking for client side. Your Expression returned the follwoing error message: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?s)^(?![\\s\\S]*<[^>]*>)[\\s\\S]*/:

Comment: I am sorry, was in a hurry. Surely the `(?s)` should have been removed.

Comment: I deleted my comment to make sure that I did not confuse anyone else. The answer above works as described.